# Get the intersection of two sets in HQL

Tags: grails, collections, hql, grails-orm

I'm having some trouble with HQL.

I'd like to do a rather complex query, I have the following Domain-Object (simplified):

```
class SomeObject {
    Set<SomeOtherObject> otherObjects
}
```

I now want to get all objects which have contain one or more of a specified list of other objects. Additionally I want also have a blacklist which otherObjects the object must not contain.

I made it this far, I can specify only one blacklist-item and a list of "allowed" otherObjects:

```
select o from Object as o 
join o.otherObjects as otherObject 
where 
    otherObject in :allowedotherobjects 
    and :excludedotherobject not in elements(o.otherObjects)
```

Basically I want something like this (which is not possible):

```
select o from Object as o 
join o.otherObjects as otherObject 
where 
    otherObject in :allowedotherobjects 
    and elements(:excludedotherobjects) not in elements(o.otherObjects)
```

btw this is a grails project I'm working on, but I'd like to solve this problem in HQL.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select o from Object as o 
join o.otherObjects as otherObject 
where 
    otherObject in :allowedotherobjects 
    and otherObject not in :excludedotherobjects
```

Comment: Another option is to query from SomeOtherObject, which would be easier.

Comment: This does not seem to work, its like the part "and otherObject not in :excludedotherobjects" is not doing anything. How would you do the Query from otherObject?